# How to interpret this notation

Tags: notation, supremum-and-infimum

**Definition 9.1.** Let $f$ and $g$ be two maps. The $C^0$-distance between $f$ and $g$, written $d_0(f,g)$, is given by
$$d_0(f,g)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert$$
The $C^r$-distance $d_r(f,g)$ is given by
$$d_r(f,g)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\{\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert,\vert f'(x)-g'(x)\vert,\dots,\vert f^{(n)}(x)-g^{(n)}(x)\vert\}$$

How do I interpret this notation?
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\sup_{1\ge i\ge n}\vert f^{(i)}(x)-g^{(i)}(x)\vert$$
or
$$\sup_{1\ge i\ge n}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert f^{(i)}(x)-g^{(i)}(x)\vert$$
Are these equal? Also, when can you swap the $\sup$s? If both indexes run in a finite set then yes. What about other combinations? (finite-infinite or infinite-infinite)

This is from Robert L. Devaney's Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All it means is that you find the value of $x$ that maximizes the distance between two functions (or their derivatives, or second derivatives...).

You cannot always swap $sup$s, however, in the infinite case.